# Compare one value with other values within a group SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I have below table where column names are `Item`, `Point` and `IsCorrect`.

```
Item | Point | IsCorrect | Not actual column, just logic 
-----+-------+-----------+--------------------
1    | 5     | 0         | 5 >= 6 
1    | 8     | 0         | 8 >= 6 
1    | 9     | 0         | 9 >= 6 
1    | 6     | 1         | 6 >= 6 

2    | 8     | 0         | 8 >= 7 
2    | 7     | 1         | 7 >= 7 
2    | 8     | 0         | 8 >= 7 
2    | 9     | 0         | 9 >= 7 

3    | 2     | 0         | 2 >= 9 
3    | 5     | 0         | 5 >= 9 
3    | 8     | 0         | 8 >= 9 
3    | 9     | 1         | 9 >= 9
```

I want to first group by Item, get a Point value where IsCorrect = 1, compare it with other point values (as shown in 4th column). If all condition matched within a group, then select that item. I am expecting following result.

```
Item | Point | IsCorrect
-----+-------+----------
2    | 8     | 0
2    | 7     | 1
2    | 8     | 0
2    | 9     | 0
```

I want to use partition, not group by. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions come to mind:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             max(case when iscorrect = 1 then point end) over (partition by item) as point_correct,
             min(point) over (partition by item) as min_point
      from t
     ) t
where min_point >= point_correct;
```

You could also do this with a subquery.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.item in (select t2.item
                 from t t2
                 group by t2.item
                 having min(t2.point) >= min(case when t2.iscorrect then point end)
                );
```

That is, for each item, compare the *minimum* `point` value to the "correct" `point` value.